# WSDL error in parsing process

Tags: soap, wsdl, parsing

I have been trying to parse a WDSL file in FuseIt and also in SFDC, but I get an error that it is not allowing me to generate the apex classes I need.

**This the error I get in SFDC:**

> Apex Generation Failed
>     No type specified for element name

**And this is the one om FuseIT:**

> Unable to determine parameterType for 'name' Parameter name: parameterTypeInfo.ParameterType

**This is the WSDL I'm trying to parse:**

```
<wsdl:definitions
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:tns="http://schemas.telecomframework.cordys.com/1.0/external/SubmitOrder"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:inst="http://schemas.cordys.com/bpm/instance/1.0"
name="SubmitOrder"
targetNamespace="http://schemas.telecomframework.cordys.com/1.0/external/SubmitOrder">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:cws="http://schemas.cordys.com/cws/1.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:tns1="http://schemas.telecomframework.cordys.com/1.0/external/SubmitOrder"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://schemas.telecomframework.cordys.com/1.0/external/SubmitOrder">
        <xsd:import
            namespace="http://schemas.cordys.com/bpm/instance/1.0"
        />
        <xsd:element
            name="body">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element
                        name="order">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element
                                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                    name="orderType"
                                    type="xs:string"
                                />
                                <xsd:element
                                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                    name="requestor"
                                    type="xs:string"
                                />
                                <xsd:element
                                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                    name="externalOrderId"
                                    type="xs:string"
                                />
                                <xsd:element
                                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                    name="relatedOrderId"
                                    type="xs:string"
                                />
                                <xsd:element
                                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                    name="interactionDateTime"
                                    type="xs:dateTime"
                                />
                                <xsd:element
                                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                    name="description"
                                    type="xs:string"
                                />
                                <xsd:element
                                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                    name="purchaseOrderNumber"
                                    type="xs:string"
                                />
                                <xsd:element
                                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                    name="requestedDate"
                                    type="xs:dateTime"
                                />
                                <xsd:element
                                    name="orderCharacteristics">
                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element
                                                maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                                minOccurs="0"
                                                name="orderCharacteristic">
                                                <xsd:complexType>
                                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                                        <xsd:element
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
name="name"
type="xs:string"
                                                        />
                                                        <xsd:element
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
name="value"
type="xs:string"
                                                        />
                                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                                </xsd:complexType>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element
                                    name="lineItems">
                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element
                                                name="lineItem">
                                                <xsd:complexType>
                                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                                        <xsd:element
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
name="itemName"
type="xs:string"
                                                        />
                                                        <xsd:element
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
name="action"
type="xs:string"
                                                        />
                                                        <xsd:element
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
name="lineItemId"
type="xs:int"
                                                        />
                                                        <xsd:element
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
name="itemId"
type="xs:long"
                                                        />
                                                        <xsd:element
name="itemCharacteristics">
<xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element
                        maxOccurs="unbounded"
                        minOccurs="0"
                        name="itemCharacteristic">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element
                                                name="name">
                                                                </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element
                                                name="value">
                                                                </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element
                                                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                                name="action"
                                                type="xs:string"
                                        />
                                </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
                                                        </xsd:element>
                                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                                </xsd:complexType>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
            name="Result">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element
                        name="Status"
                        type="xsd:string"
                    />
                    <xsd:element
                        name="Reference"
                        type="xsd:string"
                    />
                    <xsd:element
                        name="Errors"
                        type="xsd:string"
                    />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
            name="SubmitOrder">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element
                        ref="tns1:header"
                    />
                    <xsd:element
                        ref="tns1:body"
                    />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
            name="header">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        name="correlationId"
                        type="xs:string"
                    />
                    <xsd:element
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        name="messageType"
                        type="xs:string"
                    />
                    <xsd:element
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        name="sender"
                        type="xs:string"
                    />
                    <xsd:element
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        name="receiver"
                        type="xs:string"
                    />
                    <xsd:element
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        name="submissionTime"
                        type="xs:dateTime"
                    />
                    <xsd:element
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        name="messageId"
                        type="xs:short"
                    />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
            name="SubmitOrderResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element
                        ref="tns1:Result"
                    />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:cws="http://schemas.cordys.com/cws/1.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://schemas.cordys.com/bpm/instance/1.0">
        <xsd:element
            name="headerInput">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element
                        name="target"
                        type="xsd:string"
                    />
                    <xsd:element
                        name="source">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute
                                name="type"
                                type="xsd:string"
                            />
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
            name="bpm">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element
                        name="instance_id"
                        type="xsd:string"
                    />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message
    name="SubmitOrderInput">
    <wsdl:part
        name="body"
        element="tns:SubmitOrder"
    />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message
    name="SubmitOrderOutput">
    <wsdl:part
        name="body"
        element="tns:SubmitOrderResponse"
    />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message
    name="HeaderOutput">
    <wsdl:part
        name="BPMHeaderOutput"
        element="inst:bpm"
    />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType
    name="SubmitOrder">
    <wsdl:operation
        name="SubmitOrder">
        <wsdl:input
            message="tns:SubmitOrderInput"
        />
        <wsdl:output
            message="tns:SubmitOrderOutput"
        />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding
    name="SubmitOrder"
    type="tns:SubmitOrder">
    <soap:binding
        style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
    />
    <wsdl:operation
        name="SubmitOrder">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction=""
            style="document"
        />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body
                use="literal"
            />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body
                use="literal"
            />
            <soap:header
                message="tns:HeaderOutput"
                part="BPMHeaderOutput"
                use="literal"
            />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service
    name="SubmitOrderService">
    <wsdl:port
        name="SubmitOrderPort"
        binding="tns:SubmitOrder">
        <soap:address
            location="http://CordysServer/SubmitOrder.asmx"
        />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

So if anyone can give me some subjection in where I can start looking it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the itemCharacteristic element.

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="itemCharacteristic">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="name" />
            <xsd:element name="value" />
            <xsd:element xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="action" type="xs:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Note that the `name` and `value` elements have no type defined. This is more or less what the error messages are indicating, but it can be a bit difficult to isolate as there are so many name elements. Future releases of the FuseIT Wsdl2Apex tooling I'll include the element path. E.g.

> Unable to determine parameterType for 'name' from element body_order_lineItems_lineItem_itemCharacteristics_itemCharacteristic_element

I manually appended `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="xs:string"` to each of those elements and could then generate the Apex classes.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, that did it. After appending that line to those two elements I was able to generate the apex classes.